# Declaring a winner in a coin toss game

Tags: c, coin-flipping

So, I'm running into an issue with the end of this program.  It is supposed to award ten points for each correctly guessed coin flip, and at the end of the 100 tosses, a percentage of correct answers for each player as well as a total score, and finally it is to declare a winner.  I seem to have the percentage correct, but the output for total score is jibberish, and I don't know how to get the program to use the results to declare a winner.  Help?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int flip();

int main(void)
{
    int player, side, toss, turn = 1, heads = 0, tails = 0;
    int Play, wrong1, right1, wrong2, right2, r = (rand() % 2);

    puts("Oh boy.  My favorite game.  Flip the coin.  How super exciting.  I apparently am little more than a childs plaything...  \nEven though I am a program and thus do not have thumbs, hands, feet, skin or even a body, I will (reluctanly) play your silly little game, and 'flip a coin' 100 times.\nI hope you know, there are a lot better things I could be doing right now...\nReal quick, here's a list of things I could be doing right now.\n--Advance scientific research on globular clusters in the Milky Way Galaxy\n---Find the cure for cancer\n----Calculate the rate of deforestation in the Amazon\n-----Create the next generation of low emmission motor vehicles to lower the amount of CO2 in the atmosphere.\nBut, no.  Let's play 'Flip the coin'.  I couldn't possibly be more ecstatic, than if I woke this morning to see that I was on fire.  While stapled to a wall.  In New Jersey.  With Kim Kardashian holding the fire extinguisher that is actually a can of hairspray...  Yeah.\n");
    puts("Are you player 1 or player 2?\n");//question to prompt user response
    scanf_s("%d", &player);//how many players input
    puts("\nSo, let's flip a coin, because apparently this game is the 'bees-nees' of the tech world...  Enter 1 for heads, or 0 for tails.");
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));// seed random function with current time

    for (toss = 1; toss <= 100; toss++) 
    { //number of runs/tosses
        if ( player=1)
        if (turn == 1)                                                            // start of 2 player gaming
            printf("\nPlayer 1, flip the coin.  Player 2, take a guess.\n");// player 1 flip
        else
            printf("\nPlayer 2, it's your turn to flip the coin, Player 1 guess heads or tails.\n");     // player 2 flip

        if (turn == 1)
            Play = 1, turn = 0;
        else
            Play = 2, turn = 1;
        printf("\nPlayer 1 toss the coin and guess the side\n");
        int flipped;
        scanf_s("\n %d", &side);// coin guess function
        printf("\nThe coin came up %d\n", flip());

        if (side == flip() && Play == 1)
            right1++;
        else
            wrong1++;

        if (side == flip() && Play == 2)
            right2--;
        else
            wrong2++;
        if (flip() == 1)
            heads++;
        else
            tails++;
    }
    printf("heads was flipped %d times\n", heads);
    printf("tails was flipped %d times\n", tails);
    printf("Player 1 score %d \n", (right1 * 10) - (wrong1 * 5));// not working quite right player 1 eqation 1       //functions on the next 4 lines for score and confidence
    printf("Player 1 confidence %d %'\n", (right1 * 2));//percent confidence player 1   Equation 2
    printf("Player 2 score %d \n", (right2 * 10) - (wrong2 * 5));// not working quite right player 2 eqation 1
    printf("Player 2 confidence %d %'\n", (right1 * 2));//percent confidence player 2   Equation 2
    return 0;

}
int flip()// Coin flip function
{
    int i = rand() % 2;
    if (i == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: `if ( player=1)` --> `if ( player==1)`

Comment: Enable compiler warnings. Read them.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest properly formatting nested `if` statements with brackets and indentation.

```
if ( player=1)
if (turn == 1)                                                            // start of 2 player gaming
    printf("\nPlayer 1, flip the coin.  Player 2, take a guess.\n");// player 1 flip
else
    printf("\nPlayer 2, it's your turn to flip the coin, Player 1 guess heads or tails.\n");     // player 2 flip
```

is much more difficult to read than

```
if ( player=1) {
    if (turn == 1) {                  // start of 2 player gaming
        printf("\nPlayer 1, flip the coin.  Player 2, take a guess.\n");// player 1 flip
    } else {
        printf("\nPlayer 2, it's your turn to flip the coin, Player 1 guess heads or tails.\n");     // player 2 flip
    }
}
```

And yes, as mentioned in the comments

```
if ( player=1) {
```

should be

```
if (player == 1) {
```

And

```
if (turn == 1)
    Play = 1, turn = 0;
else
    Play = 2, turn = 1;
```

should be

```
if (turn == 1) {
    Play = 1;
    turn = 0;
} else {
    Play = 2;
    turn = 1;
}
```

And you are also using `right1`, `wrong1`, `right2`, and `wrong2` without initializing them.

And finally, in `printf()`, `%'` should be `%%` if you are trying to print a percent sign.

Comment: Awesome.  Forgetting to declare, that's a very 8th level error... 
 So, I did that stuff, and I'm not getting nonsense numbers, but my issue now is that Visual Studio is giving me errors that rand, time and srand identifiers can't be found.  The program works in an online compiler but not VS 17...  Any suggestions there?  Besides not using VS...  It's what we were given to use in class, so...  And btw, thank you so much for you help so far guys.  I'm thankful that ya'll are tehre.

Comment: can you update the question with your current code, and the exact errors VS is giving you?

Comment: So now it's working in visual, but not online...  Updating working code to above.